# WSUS Not offiering December patch for 1809 LTSC (and possibly Office 2016)

Tags: wsus

PCs here are on 1809 LTSC. November was the lasts patch WSUS offered.
I know 1809 came out of support Nov 2020 for non-LTSC versions. LTSC is supposed to be supported for many years to come.

Also, I haven't received the Jan 2021 Non-security MS Office updates for Office 2016 which were just released.

So I'm not sure if this is a Windows 10 LTSC issue, or something bigger.
I've checked my products and classifications and they are correct. (windows 10, Security updates)
I've also run a clean up on the DB

I haven't made changes to WSUS for a very long time, so it's not something I changed that causing this.

Any ideas? Suggestions?
thanks

Comment: Are you the administrator of the WSUS?

Comment: Yes............